# weekdays in correct order based on Locale with java.time API

Tags: java, java-time

Some countries like Germany start the week from Monday and some countries like the US start the week from Sunday.
I was thinking that dayOfWeek.value has a version based on Locale, but I can't find it.
Is there a way to get weekdays in the correct order dependently on Locale with java.time API

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need [`WeekFields`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/WeekFields.html), which has an `of` method that takes a `Locale`.

Here's some code that gets you a list of the days of week in order:

```
DayOfWeek firstDay = WeekFields.of(someLocale).getFirstDayOfWeek();
List<DayOfWeek> list = IntStream.range(0, 7)
    .mapToObj(x -> firstDay.plus(x))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 4):

[DayOfWeek](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/DayOfWeek.html) doesn't support localized textual form, you need `WeekFields`

> **This enum provides access to the localized textual form of the day-of-week. Some locales also assign different numeric values to the days, declaring Sunday to have the value 1, however this class provides no support for this.** See [WeekFields](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/WeekFields.html) for localized week-numbering.

```
WeekFields germany = WeekFields.of(Locale.GERMANY);

System.out.println(germany.getFirstDayOfWeek());  //MONDAY

WeekFields us = WeekFields.of(Locale.US);

System.out.println(us.getFirstDayOfWeek());     //SUNDAY
```